# Remove slash from bundle file path (webpack)

Tags: webpack

[image]

Above you can see scripts in my `HTML` file which generated by `webpack` , in case of adding slash before path , it looks to localhost:port/bundleFile.js what cause of next error:

[image]

When I've changed output param `publicPath` to `''` (`publicPath: ''`) it still doesn't work . What should I add to my webpack config , to prevent adding this slash and make scripts look like this ?

```
<script async="" data-chunk="browser" src="browser.js"></script>
```

path to `browser.js` file is `dist/browser.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a particular folder in which you save all files. So, the by default path will be in the current folder.

Comment: could you pls give me solution for my particular case ?